# B-1/B-2 visa rejected, reapply?

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, german-residents, mongolian-citizens

I applied for a B-1/B-2 visa in early October and was rejected. I am in a long distance relationship and my boyfriend studies in US. At that time I wanted to celebrate Christmas with him. I am in Germany right now but actually a Mongolian. Here is the interview:

> Q: Good afternoon, English or Deutsch?
>   A: It doesn't matter, OK English.
>   Q: Why are you going to US?
>   A: Want to celebrate Christmas with my boyfriend.
>   Q: How long are you going to stay in US?
>   A: Approximately two weeks.
>   Q: What do you do here in Germany?
>   A: Going to study. I am not yet in a University but in a language
>   course.
>   Q: How long were you here in Germany?
>   A: For three months now.

And he said that I was denied.

Now I am officially a student here in Germany and am living here for about eight months.

Do you think they will give me a visa this time?

P.S. Does the interview language matter, is German better?

Comment: Now i want to visit my boyfriend for my school break

Comment: And he asked me if i was in US before and my answeR was yes. Eventhough i was in us before they refused and i have to be careful this time

Comment: @pnuts i have 2 year visa or what we call it here Aufenthaltserlaubnis

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with US procedures, but I believe that they want to confirm that you'll go back to Germany.

- If your German is good enough for the interview, that should be a big plus. It shows that you've put plenty of effort into fitting into **German** society.
- If you are now accepted as a student, and if you have already earned credit points towards your BA or MA, that's another incentive for you to go back.

Comment: it is my first semester now and i dont have any earned credits